# Clarification on Observer Pattern

Tags: observer-pattern

I was learning about the Observer Pattern for a Python project I'm working on. I really like the idea as it seems like a good way to decouple classes and modules. (such as UI and backend for example?)

Anyways, I reviewed [THIS](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/python/1) example. It's very clear that the Subject should have a list of Observers so it can update them through the _notify function. However, I don't understand why in the attach function, we assign an _subject variable for the observer.

I have been using this pattern based on the example. So far, I've had no use of the _subject variable in my Observer objects. So I'm pretty confused why it's even there?

Answer (score 0):

The _subject variable in the Observer seems to be redundant. This is because the Observer by default knows the Subject to which it registers.

Although, you are referring to the pattern in Python, I regularly use this pattern in Java and no requirement of such a field exists.